# How can I re-format dates coming out of FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the below code to show a tooltip on each event:

```
      eventAfterRender: function (event, element) {
        element.popover({
          animation: false,
          container: '#calendar',
          content: 'The selected booking starts at ' + event.start + ' and ends at ' + event.end,
          placement: 'auto',
          title: event.title
        });
      },
```

but the message ends up as

> The selected booking starts at 1404345600000 and ends at
>   1404345600000.

How can I make the format in this message `DD-MM-YY`?

**Edit:** There is a function `parseDate` available. What is the correct way to wrap it around `event.start`?

Comment: I would be more concerned in why your start and end values are the same... maybe your approach is not correct

Comment: FullCalendar has a parameter called:
    timeFormat: 'DD-MM-YY'

Comment: @Bardo because that's what I added as a test. Anyway that is not the question.

Comment: @Jackson That doesn't have an effect on `event.start` output etc.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your date there is a function called formatDate
that takes a date as first parameter and then a string representing the
output expected pattern.

Here is the documentation page that gives you all the patterns and their
equivalence.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs1/utilities/formatDate/

Hope it can help!